# PHP SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I am super frustrated with a php soap error and this keeps me occupied since one week already. I really hope you can help me, I would be very pleased!

I have switched from nusoap to php soap, but i am getting a strange error message now:

> SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'name' property in …

I have about 50 parameters in my wsdl and I actually don’t want to send each parameter with empty value.
Is there a possibility to set an option on soapClient to fill automatically empty parameters??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add minOccurs="0" to the element